# Cannot implicitly convert system.directoryservice.accountmanager.userprinciple to extended userprincipal

Tags: c#

I have created a class and derived class. How do I call the derived class from another class? See below class, derived class(extended class), and the place where i am calling derived class.

`UserPrincipal` class:

```
private UserPrincipal GetUserFromAD1(string userLoginName)
{
        String currentUser = userLoginName;
        String domainName = userLoginName.Split('\\')[0];
        UserPrincipal user = null;

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
            {

                user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.IdentityType.SamAccountName, currentUser);

            }
        });
        return user;
    }
```

Extended `UserPrincipal` class:

```
    [DirectoryObjectClass("user")]
    [DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]

    public class UserPrincipalExtended : UserPrincipal
    {
        public UserPrincipalExtended(PrincipalContext context): base(context)                

        {

        }
        [DirectoryProperty("department")]
        public string department
        {
            get
            {
                if (ExtensionGet("department").Length != 1)
                    return null;
                return (string)ExtensionGet("department")[0];
            }
            set { this.ExtensionSet("department", value); }
        }
```

METHOD

```
private void GetUserInfoFromAD1()
{
        try
        {

            XPathNavigator rootNode = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
            this.initialData = rootNode.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:Wrapper", this.NamespaceManager).OuterXml;
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    UserPrincipalExtended userFromAD = this.GetUserFromAD1(web.CurrentUser.LoginName);
```

On the code line

```
this.GetUserFromAD1(web.CurrentUser.LoginName)
```

I am getting an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type .......

Comment: Please provide the **complete and accurate** error message!

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type` the rest of that error message is pretty important... and you've left it out for some reason.

Comment: If `D : B` and you have a reference to `B`, the compiler cannot perform an implicit conversion to `D` since it cannot be sure the type is actually a `D`. Just cast it if you know it is or use the `as operator`.

Comment: 1              Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal' to 'EmployeeEngagementForm.FormCode.UserPrincipalExtended'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be attempting to assign an instance of `UserPrincipal` returned from `GetUserFromAD1` to a variable of type `UserPrincipalExtended`.

That isn't a type conversion that can be performed implicitly.

You can implicitly assign an instance of a type to its supertype (or a supertype thereof or an interface that it implements).

You cannot implicitly assign an instance of a type to a subtype of that type.

Please consider implementing `department` as an extension method on `UserPrincipal` or making `UserPrincipalExtended` a wrapper for an instance of `UserPrincipal`, or provide a cast operator to cast `UserPrincipal` to an `UserPrincipalExtended`, or use a copy constructor.

There are a number of designs that will work for this. The one you have written will not.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal' to 'EmployeeEngagementForm.FormCode.UserPrincipalExtended'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I am new to C# programming , plese take me as begineers

Comment: Have you done any object oriented programming? Do you understand that C# is a strongly typed language? Do you know what I mean by supertype and subtype?

Comment: My questions (in the above comment) are an attempt to ascertain how best to explain this to you. What parts of my explanation are unclear to you?